# Phaser 3 - How to reference the object itself from within arrow functions events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, this, phaser-framework, arrow-functions

I have this scenario where I create 5 buttons dinamically and load a custom property to it (mydata):

```
create() {
    for (var a=1; a<=5; a++) {
        this.mybutton = this.add.image(a*50, 10, '').setInteractive();
        this.mybutton.mydata = a;
        this.mybutton.on('pointerup', (e) => {
           // how to return mydata property value??
        });
    }
}
```

I found online that **e.target** or **e.currentTarget** could help but in this case both returned undefined.

Anyway, knowing that arrow functions move *this* to the parent scope, there is still a way to reference the object itself in an event and retrieve its properties?

*PS: I know that I could achieve the desired result with the use of regular functions but I am studying arrow functions now so I am a bit "into it" and then I would like to know if there is a turnaround in this particular way.*

Thanks!

**EDIT - I ended figuring the solution:**

```
create() {
    for (let a=1; a<=5; a++) {
        const mybutton = this.add.image(a*50, 10, '').setInteractive();
        mybutton.mydata = a;
        mybutton.on('pointerup', (e) => {
           console.log (mybutton); // returns the object
           console.log (mybutton.mydata); // returns the property
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For me current-target works fine

```
$('#test').on("pointerup", (e) =>
{
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afnoLtb2/1/